# Pass and edit specific character in string

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass in a memory reference to a character in a string and edit it in a function using C. The code is below:

```
void EditChar(char *input) {
printf("# %s #",*input);
*input = *input << 1
    }

int main() {
char *string ="aaaa";
EditChar(&string[2]);
printf("%s",string);
}
```

I can print the character inside the function fine which I presume must mean it's following the pointer so why am I unable to edit the pointer location of that character, any ideas?

Comment: Probably because when you write a **string literal** like `"aaaa"`, those four letters are put in a read-only data segment in the computer's memory.  They are `const`, you can't change them.

Comment: Your code shouldn't be compiling (certainly not without warnings) because you don't pass a `bit` to `EditChar()`.  You also don't use the variable, but two wrongs don't really make a right.

Comment: oops sorry meant to delete that variable from the function it's something i plan to use once i make sure this is working correctly, do either of you two know how I can edit the value of the string if it is const. I'm only using the string aaaa to test the function when it works the string will be a variable read in from file

Comment: Replace `"aaaa"` with `strdup("aaaa")`.  That gives you a copy (a duplicate) of the string.  The copy is not in read-only memory.  (It uses `malloc` to get some memory you can change, then copies the old string into that memory.  If you're using this seriously in a program, remember to `free` that memory when you're finished using it.)

Comment: Or use: `char string[] = "aaaa";`

Comment: That's brilliant thanks the problem was with the way I was testing the function not the function itself! *epic face palm* if you put it as an answer I can accept it, thank you so much :)

Comment: I like Jonathan's solution better than mine (it's simpler), so I'll let him write the answer and collect the karma.

Comment: `char *string  = "aaaa";` allocates memory in read-only segment..this type of declaration is used for `CONSTANTS`..

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack of a ; on line 3 is going to cause problems to start with.

You're passing a character instead of a character pointer on line 2.

And on my mac, once you fix those problems, you get a bus error on line 3 because you're trying to change read-only memory.

char *string =strdup("aaaa");

and now it works.

Also, as stated in question comments, instead of strdup, you may want to use

char string[] = "aaaa";